# Accessing UITabBarController for child viewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

If I am using UITabBarController Item1 and Item2 viewControllers are displayed properly. But UITabBarButtonItem is not displaying item1's redirect page. UITabBarButtonItem must display on all pages .

[image]

My problem is UITabBarButtonItem is does not display the childViewController(red page). How to display the UITabBarButtonItem to childViewController?

Comment: Make sure for redViewController `Hide Bottombar on Push` is unselected

Comment: No sir, UITabBarButtonItem have a Enable Property. Does not have a Hide property

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: @vignesh-j :  I asked you to select your redViewController in story board, open its property inspector there will be option called `Hide Bottombar on Push` make sure its unselected :) Thats exactly what Ahmad said in his answer

Comment: @SandeepBhandari the issue seems to be there is no navigation controller; If I'm not mistaking, this property should work as expected only with a navigation controller, check: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621863-hidesbottombarwhenpushed

Comment: @ahmad-f : true, it wont work because if there is no navigation controller you cant push :) And property says `Hide Bottombar on Push` for the absolute same reason :) He might be presenting red VC in that case there is no way he can show tab bar on red :)

Comment: @ahmad-f : What confuses me though is the symbol on segue between blue and red VC it clearly is the symbol of push :) If there is no navigation controller anywhere in nav stack then this should crash :) You cant push something with nav controller but OP says he can push things but doesn't see tab bar item, so I presume there is a navigation controller in that case this property should be enough to show bar

Comment: Yes sir. When I add the navigation bar. displaying UITabBarButtonItem on redViewController.

Comment: "If there is no navigation controller anywhere in nav stack then this should crash" No @SandeepBhandari, that was an older behavior :) for now, in this case it would be considered as present instead of crashing.

Comment: Thanks sir It's Working.

Comment: @ahmad-f : hmmmm that sounds interesting, can you please further provide me with links or something to read more on that

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari Thanks for Help :)

Comment: @vignesh-j : Am glad I could be of help :) Please go ahead and accept Ahmad's answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should embed the first view controller in the hierarchy (the blue view controller) in a *navigation controller*. Then, in the red view controller, make sure that [`hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621863-hidesbottombarwhenpushed) property is set to `false`:

```
// for instance, let's assume that you will do it in the `viewDidLoad()`:
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false

    // ...
}
```

Or if you want to achieve from the interface builder, select the red view controller and from the attribute inspector and make sure that the "Hide Bottom Bar on Push" option is unchecked:

[image]

Otherwise, if there is no navigation controller (presenting instead of pushing), there is no way to display the bottom bar in the red view controller.

Comment: Thanks sir for your helping. When I add the navigation bar. displaying UITabBarButtonItem on redViewController.